# C++ Overloading operator+ in the case of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I m new on c++ programing and i have to release a Set implementation for a teacher.

I have to overload operator+ as non-member function of my class Set (which should be a template class).

The problem i got is that error (at compilation): opertor+(Set, const Set&) must take either zero or one argument.

BUT my non member function IS NOT on my class Set, and so this function is supposed to take 2 parameters. I m really disapointed ...

here is my code :

```
#ifndef GUARD_set_h
#define GUARD_set_h

#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Set
{
public:
    Set() {}
    Set(const T arr[], size_t arr_sz)
    {
        std::set<T> m_set;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < arr_sz; ++i)
            m_set.insert(arr[i]);

    }
    Set(const std::vector<T>& vec)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
            m_set.insert(vec[i]);
    }

    Set(const std::set<T>& st)
    {
        m_set = st;
    }

    Set(const Set& set_to_copy)
    {
        m_set = set_to_copy.m_set;
    }

    Set& operator +=(const Set& st) // Addition Assignement operator
    {
        for (typename std::set<T>::iterator it = st.m_set.begin(); it != st.m_set.end(); ++it)
            m_set.insert(*it);
        return *this;
    }

    private:
    std::set<T> m_set;
};

    template <class T>
    Set<T> Set<T>::operator+(Set, const Set&) // Set Union
    {

    }

#endif
```

Here is the error:
error: 'Set Set::operator+(Set, const Set&)' must take either zero or one argument

I already ask you sorry for my approximate English, and thanks you for help :D

Comment: You've defined it as a member of your `Set<T>` class. You have to remove the `Set<T>::` prefix from the function.

Comment: If your `operator +` is non member, why you have `Set<T>::` in front of it?

Comment: Remove the scope resolution `Set<T>::` since it's not part of your `Set` class as you say.

Comment: Ty for being so fast =) but now i get other errors "declaration of 'operator+' as non-fucntion', 'missing template arguments before ',' token' (same line of course) and finally 'expected primary-expression before 'const')

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your non-member `operator +` as follows:

```
template <class T>
Set<T> operator+(const Set<T>& a, const Set<T>& b)
{
//implementation
}
```

Change your first parameter to `const reference` as you are creating unnecessary copy.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer on member vs. non-member. But as for taking the first parameter by copy - the operator returns by value, so a copy will be made anyway, and taking a parameter by value is not slower (and can be significantly faster) than taking by reference and copying internally. [Want speed? Pass by value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/).

Comment: @Angew : Thanks for the link, But if I understand correctly, to effectively make use of copy elision, we should be using the first parameter(which is passed by value) to have the final result of `operator +` and return that, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So instead of defining a local `Set<T> result;` and returning that, you simply operate on the parameter `a` all along. Also note that even if copy elision doesn't kick in, C++11 move semantics will (assuming the first argument is an rvalue, of course).